# Crystal report Formular error when data source empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

This question is not new but i'm stuck all day. Someone has posted before: [Crystal Reports: Error on Sum in Formula Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424768/crystal-reports-error-on-sum-in-formula-field?rq=1) .i have report that calculate total revenue in formular call revenue :

```
 if isnull({table.totalAmount}) and isnull({table.unpaidAmount})then 0 else 
{table.totalAmount}-{table.unpaidAmount}
```

it work if datasource not empty but if datasource empty it throw exception :`Error in formula revenue: A number,current amount, date, time, or date-time is required here`
Any advice on how to solve this would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal is throwing an exception, more than likely this is because the datatype for {table.totalAmount} and/or {table.unpaidAmount} is a String rather than a number?

You can convert them to numbers:

```
ToNumber({table.totalAmount}) 
ToNumber({table.unpaidAmount})
```

Alternately you can run a check to see if the data is numeric or not:

```
If IsNumeric({table.totalAmount}) and IsNumeric({table.unpaidAmount})
Then {table.totalAmount}-{table.unpaidAmount}
Else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

when datasource is empty `isnull` is not getting any value hence the error. try like this:

```
if ({table.totalAmount}="" and {table.unpaidAmount}="")
then 0 
else 
{table.totalAmount}-{table.unpaidAmount}
```